# Find the number of times some functions are called in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to find the number of times some functions are called in my code. Here's a big overview:

```
void entryFunction(){
    bool use64bit = true
    ...some calculation to determine how many bits to use
    if (use64bit){
        countThisFunction64();
    }
    else{
        countThisFunction256();
    }
}
```

In the above example, I want to count the number of times "countThisFunction64()" and "countThisFunction256()" are called. "EntryFunction()" itself is called from another source file, so using static globals are not my first preference. I'll make changes to use static call counters only as my last option.

I'm more interested in knowing if there is an elegant way to do this? I have only cursory knowledge of how profilers and debuggers work, certainly not enough to hack/implement one without help. I'm using VS with the MSVC++ compiler, so my executable can be built with debugging symbols. I'm wondering if I can run my executable as usual, attach a debugger or run a profiling tool or something else to get the call counts alone out. I know profiling tools report how many times a function was called, so it's certainly possible to do it. Can somebody tell me the easiest way for me to do this? Maybe Visual Studio itself has some tools I don't know about?

Comment: You can use local `static` variables and increment for each case.

Comment: Profiler is definitely the way to go. Never profiled c++ code before, but I know it's possible. I'd definitely focus on that. Profilers are extremely handy tools.

Comment: And if you will do a bit more research, and find some profiler working for you, you may gain lot more than just some number. It may take more effort, but if you are hunting performance and not just statistics, that profiling tool will be essential.

Comment: @Ped7g IIRC VS comes with an inbuilt one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ then it may be even less effort than adding static counter... :)

Comment: VS does come with one, though I've never used it. VTune is the profiling tool I usually use, simply because I'm familiar with it from my grad school days. After some research into the options in VTune, I see this [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/calculating-estimated-call-counts-with-intel-vtune-amplifier-xe-2013). Not an exact call count for performance reasons, but fairly acceptable to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it and it works, local static variables are shared to multiple files

```
#include "test1.h"
#include "test2.h"

int main()
{
   callerTest1();
   callerTest2();
   entryFunction();
}

//call.h
void entryFunction()
{
    static int ctr = 0; 
    ++ctr; 
    std::cout << ctr;
}


//test2.h
#include "call.h"
void callerTest1()
{
    entryFunction();
}

//test1.h
#include "call.h"
void callerTest2()
{
    entryFunction();
}
```

Comment: Hey Lorence, no doubt that this works. What I called "entryFunction()" here is called millions of times in my code. I don't fancy grepping through huge debug logs or stdout. Like I said, I'll do this as a last option. I'm hoping to learn about new tools/knowledge about doing this through code instrumentation/debuggers etc. Thanks for making the effort though